# creating keys recursively in registry editor in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I need to create a keys recursively in register editor in windows using power shell. `md HKLM:\Software\a\b\c` in this command b and c keys will be create only if parent key a exists, but I want to create `a\b\c` recursively. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-Force` parameter:

```
PS C:\> md HKLM:\Software\a\b\c
PS C:\> Test-Path HKLM:\Software\a\b\c
False
PS C:\> md HKLM:\Software\a\b\c -Force
PS C:\> Test-Path HKLM:\Software\a\b\c
True
```